# finding dataframe group count

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

i have a dataframe like

```
       customer         genre
0      cust1           |BIOPIC|DRAMA|
1      cust2           |COMEDY|DRAMA|ROMANCE|
2      cust1           |DRAMA|THRILLER|
3      cust3           |COMEDY|HORROR|
4      cust4           |HISTORY|ROMANCE|WAR|
5      cust3           |ADVENTURE|COMEDY|
6      cust2           |ACTION|DRAMA|THRILLER|
7      cust1           |CRIME|DRAMA|THRILLER|
8      cust3           |HISTORY|ROMANCE|WAR|
9      cust2           |ADVENTURE|COMEDY|
10     cust4           |BIOPIC|DRAMA|HISTORY|THRILLER|
```

I need = how many times each customer did transaction(customer count) and their respective genre count.Eg. cust1 DRAMA = 3, cust1  THRILLER = 2,like wise for each customer's.

I did found the each customer count by

```
df = df.groupby(['cust']).size()
```

then i know how to filter out the genres and getting the count if it was within a LIST , but i  am getting confused with how to proceed with each group of customer and getting the count for each customer's indivisual genre count.

filtering(|) from genre expression and getting the fields out.

please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature `str.get_dummies` is perfect for this sort of thing! It works just like the [dataframe version](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) but on strings and allows you to specify a delimiter. Assuming your dataframe is named `df`, then the below code does what you're after:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np   
df = pd.concat([df, df.Genres.str.get_dummies(sep='|')], axis=1)
df = df.groupby("Customers").aggregate(np.sum)

print(df)
```

output:

```
           ACTION  ADVENTURE  BIOPIC  COMEDY  CRIME  DRAMA  HISTORY  HORROR  \
Customers
cust1           0          0       1       0      1      3        0       0
cust2           1          1       0       2      0      2        0       0
cust3           0          1       0       2      0      0        1       1
cust4           0          0       1       0      0      1        2       0
```

To explain a bit, `str.get_dummies` method makes a new column for every value it sees in the column specified and then marks a 1 for the values present and a 0 elsewhere. The GroupBy and Aggregate methods make clusters according to the customers and add up the columns. Aggregate will silently drop columns which it can't add, in this case the original `Genres` column.

Comment: can we make a multi-index kind of thing under the genre field and keep each genre category(action, adventure,comedy) under that parent field genre field?

Comment: And also i don't want customer field as index. If i am doing a reset_index(), i am getting an extra field unnamed o as field and an index named o.then i need to delete that extra unnamed 0 field. Is there a way to get the normal index ,customer as a field in that code. Because it becomes hectic to proceed further with a customer field as index.

Comment: Resetting the index after the groupby and aggregate gives you a new column titled 'Customers' with the standard numeric index. I'm not sure how to do what you want with the multi-index, you might consider asking a new question.